# Webpage truncates under iOS when loaded in landscape

Tags: html, ios, browser, safari, viewport

I have a long webpage that gets truncated when it loads in landscape mode under iOS (either with Safari or Chrome).

It renders fully when loaded in portrait mode, but as soon as I flip the device to landscape and hit refresh, it gets truncated a bit beyond the bottom of the screen.

The page fully renders if do similar to `<meta name="viewport" content="height=1000">` but I don't necessarily know how high the entire page will be.

Is there a meta/content setting that will cover any page size and prevent this from happening?

Here's some simple HTML that demonstrates it; on my iDevices the page gets truncated about 2/3 down the length of the table.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<body>
    <table style="height: 800px; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black;">
        <tr><td>table</td></tr>
    </table>

    <textarea style="width: 300px; height: 150px;">text goes here</textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/497eY/2/embedded/result/